# Setup selenium webdriver with browsermob for IE

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium, browsermob

How do I create an instance of webdriver.IE that uses browsermob using Python?  Below is how i have it working with Chrome and Firefox, but I'm struggling with IE.

```
bmPath = os.path.join('thePath')
context.server = Server(bmPath)
context.server.start()
context.proxy = context.server.create_proxy()

# System.setProperty("bmp.allowNativeDnsFallback", "true");
if context.browser.lower() == 'chrome':
    co = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    co.add_argument("--proxy-server={0}".format(context.proxy.proxy))
    #co.add_argument("--proxy-server={0}".format(context.proxy.selenium_proxy()))
    pathToChromedriver = join(homePath, "drivers", "chromedriver.exe")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=pathToChromedriver, chrome_options=co)
elif context.browser.lower() == 'firefox':
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_proxy(context.proxy.selenium_proxy())
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Comment: what should be the value of bmPath? According to what I read in the docs, it is the url of server but how to decide its value? I have installed browsermobproxy using pip. In my case, what should be bmPath? I have no clue of how to proceed.

Comment: bmPath is the full path to the browsermob-proxy.bat file (on windows) or just browsermob-proxy on non-windows